# Laravel resourceful controller - differentiate an API call from a browser

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5

I have a single route defined like this:

`Route::resource('problem', 'ProblemController');`

The moment I `POST` to `/problem`, a `ProblemController@store` method is fired.

Now what I want is to return a JSON response if it's an API call or a view (or maybe redirect) if I'm on the "web-side" of my application. How can I approach this problem?

Should I create separate controllers? Should I (in every method/controller) detect the type of the request and respond accordingly? Should I use middlewares? Route groups? Separate application?

The main goal is to have multiple application types (API + versioning + web) in one package but share the business logic, models and most of the code (to avoid repeating).

I am using Laravel 5.2.

Thank you!

Comment: check `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` - this can be faked, but im guessing this isnt a security issue, just a convenience one

Comment: This variable is set when request is done using Ajax call, so it won't work if you do the request in some other manner, e.g. using curl or some rest client. Another thing is that superglobals like $_SERVER or $_GET should never be accessed directly when using a framework, as it wraps them in a series of convenience classes/methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Request object offers a method **wantsJson()** that checks **Accept** header of the request and returns **TRUE** if **JSON** was requested.

In your controller you can do the following:

```
if( request()->wantsJson() )
{
    return ['foo' => 'bar'];
}

return view('foo.bar');
```

You can read more about content negotiation in **Laravel** here: http://fideloper.com/laravel-content-negotiation

Answer (score 1):

You can create a route group like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'api'], function(){
    //All routes in this route become domain.com/api/route
});
```

This makes the most sense to me because a route that returns a view and an API route are two separate things.  You should have a controller for the pages and views you want to show in your app, and another one for the api routes that update and change your data, returning JSON.

Comment: As long as they return the same data (the same resource) it should be the same endpoint, at least to REST rules of thumbs, as in this case only resource representation changes, be it JSON, HTML, XML or anything else.

Comment: Interesting and I see why that makes sense.  In my experience the pages of an app often contain more complex elements than just a listing of one resource.  So I have page controllers and then they use ajax to consume the API and get JSON back.  Probably depends on the use case more than anything. Thanks!